# How to create a personalized user interface for iPad app?

Tags: ios, ipad, user-interface

I'm trying to create an application for the iPad but I would like to create a user interface with different styles and controls to those offered in xcode. I would like to create something with an interface like StumblUpon, Flipboard or any other applications that you can see over here http://www.iospirations.com/. I don't know if those kind of interfaces are created with custom controls or some kind of library. If any of you can give some pointers or directions for things to read or try I'll be very grateful. I don't think i can build an interface like those just dragging the standard controls...so that's why I'm completely lost here.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: You can go for webapp development rather than native development. In that way, you can decide upon your UI in html5/css

Comment: Have you found https://www.cocoacontrols.com yet? It's pretty great!

Comment: @Pritesh but if I build a web application it would be accesible from any kind of device right? any tablet and smart phone is ok but maybe is not an application I would like you to see on your web browser in your computer...I don't know if I'm right whit that concept.

Comment: @Maarten I'm going to check it right now! thanks!

Comment: Check out phonegap for ios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to build specifically. You might customise some standard components using `UIAppearance` Proxy:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

and some other components you would build from scratch, perhaps by stacking up several views and moving them around programmatically, with custom backing classes and logic. Move them around using `UIView` animations, or apply transforms to them using C drawing.

Another option might be to look at if there is any open-source components on GitHub that you could use/customize. iCarousel is a good example of this, take a look through the source code.

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Your question is very general, the bottom line is if you want a custom component you need to build it from scratch. I'd advise against doing too much of this, as it makes your code harder to maintain, harder to to keep inline with iOS updates, and usually includes doing loads of work to achieve roughly the same function that Apple gives you for free

Answer (score 0):

Another good resource (not free though) - http://www.appdesignvault.com